# What is the default encoding, used in text files in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, text-processing, encoding

I created a normal text file "input.txt" in Ubuntu. I added some data to it.  My questions are:

1. What is the default encoding, used in text files in Ubuntu?
2. How do I find its encoding technique?
3. Is there a way to change the encoding technique?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `enca` which you can use to detect and convert the encoding technique.
From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/enca.1.html)

> Enca reads given text files, or standard input when none are  given,  and  uses  knowledge
> about  their  language  (must  be  supported by you) and a mixture of parsing, statistical
> analysis, guessing and black magic to determine their encodings, which it then  prints  to
> standard output (or it confesses it doesn't have any idea what the encoding could be).
> Enca can also convert files to some other encoding ENC when you ask for it--either using a
> built-in converter, some conversion library, or by calling an external converter.